# How to Prevent Request Proxy Authentication from Client through Fiddler

Tags: android, proxy, emulation, fiddler

I am trying to force my all my network requests from the emulator through Telerik Fiddler, Currently I have managed to set everything up.

The only issue that is bothering me is that if I try to access any url from the Emulator Browser or call any API in my app, I am prompted for a proxy username and password, But I have many requests I cant be inputing for each request.

Is it possible to add these automatically from Fiddler so that in the Emulator Browser, I just type the address and nothing more?.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, have you configured Fiddler to request authentication? Or does Fiddler chain to some other upstream proxy that demands authentication? If the later, try using the Rules > Automatically Authenticate checkbox.

Comment: So, to clarify, no, you haven't configured Fiddler to request auth and yes, you do have Fiddler chained to an upstream proxy that requires credentials?

What is the value of the `Proxy-Authenticate` response header from that proxy and are the credentials it expects different than your Windows login credentials?

Comment: The  credentials are different from my windows credentials, I realized that an API call within my app was going through okay but visiting a webpage with the browser kept on asking for the user password.